# python random.setstate(), seed() - is there guarantee of same results across implementations?

Tags: python, random, python-3.x, python-2.x

Is there guarantee that pyhon2/python3 script with random generator initialized with `random.setstate()` or `random.seed()` will produce same sequence of pseudo-randomness across different versions and platforms ? (for example `python 3.1 on Mac , the same as python 3.2 on Linux 64-bit`)

Question is about both: python2 and python3, with assumption that python3 scripts will run on python3 interpreters and vice versa.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/random.html#random.seed

Comment: it does not say if python3.x and python3.y where x!=y will produce same results

Comment: If the documentation does not state that the results are guaranteed to be the same across python versions, then that's not part of the API and it's not correct to depend on it. Or, at least, this is what I think. Even though, the fact that the algorithm is mentioned may lead to ask your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 2.3 and up use the Mersenne Twister generator, which is independent of the system random function (implemented as a C extension module for Python). For any version using the Mersenne Twister, the results should be the same across versions and platforms.

Previously, you could guarantee backwards compatibility using the `WichmannHill` generator, but unfortunately it seems that has been removed in Python 3.x.

If you absolutely need to guarantee compatibility, write your own `Random` subclass (or use a stable external implementation, e.g. [simplerandom](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplerandom)) as recommended by the `random` documentation:

> Class Random can also be subclassed if you want to use a different basic generator of your own devising: in that case, override the random(), seed(), getstate(), setstate() and jumpahead() methods. Optionally, a new generator can supply a getrandbits() method — this allows randrange() to produce selections over an arbitrarily large range.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [simplerandom](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplerandom) module, which has a consistent implementation independent of the Python platform. It has support for Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2. It has 9 different algorithms.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import simplerandom.iterators as sri
>>> rng = sri.MWC1(12345)
>>> next(rng)
498186671L
>>> next(rng)
888940288L
>>> next(rng)
345072384L
```

And as long as you seed with the same value, you get the same results:

```
>>> rng = sri.MWC1(12345)
>>> next(rng)
498186671L
>>> rng = sri.MWC1(98765)
>>> next(rng)
3546724783L
```